# Field not editable for a form added via personalize in ax 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I am facing a challenge, i added two fields on the form via personalize, InventItemBarcode is the form and Description and ProductDescription(customized field), but am no able to edit the value on the form for ProductDescription, I did check AllowEdit property for the ProductDescription field on the datasource, and table(InventItemBarcode) as well, it is set to 'Yes'. But I am not able to edit the value for this field. Is there anything else I need to change? Thanks in advance. 
Following is the link for the image where the field has edit contents property checked.

[InventItemBarcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnXU2.png)

Comment: If you go to the actual table in the AOT and find the field, you have `AllowEdit` and `AllowEditOnCreate` both set to Yes? Also the actual form's datasource field?

Comment: Presumably 'ProductDescription' is not of the type '[display](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Display_method)', otherwise you would have to change it to '[edit](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Edit_method)'

Comment: I have Allow Edit and AlloEditOnCreate property set to yes on the table and  on the form data source also. But it does not give me option to edit.

Answer (score 1):

I tried setting AllowAdd property to 'yes' for the ProductDescription field on the form datasource, now it's editable. What I don't understand is the system field 'description' has AllowAdd property set to 'restricted' is editable on the form added via personalization but ProductDescription which is a customized field and added via personalization also had AllowAdd property on the datasource to 'restricted' is not editable. By changing the AllowAdd to yes it became editable. Any ideas on this?

Comment: To increase your chances for an answer on your follow-up question in your answer, try creating a new question (you can refer to this answer from there).